# Multiple menu creation in one application possible?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a multiple menu create in one application. Is this possible or not? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Noticed you edited a number of your questions, can you continue removing all tags from the beginning of your titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one menu inside an `Activity`. However, you can changing the menu items at runtime, depending on the current state of the activity. To achieve this you should override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method. This method is called every time the user opens the menu, so you can recreate the menu every time it becomes visible. Hope this helps.